# jdk1.8 == jdk8 == java8

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, synonym-request

A while ago [jdk8 was made a synonym of java-8](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197170/java-synonym-of-jdk). Since then the [jdk1.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jdk1.8) tag has appeared which should receive the same treatment in my opinion.