# Synonyms: jdk9 == java-9

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, synonym-request

I suggest doing [the same as for Java 7, 8 etc.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272305/jdk1-8-jdk8-java8):

- main tag: [java-9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-9) (17 questions)
- synonym: [jdk9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jdk9) (3 questions)